# Dividing the template conttent into three using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to perform division of tables into three in my xslt code dynamically.
Give me structure to append my text at specific node like if i am having 100 nodes i need to append my text at 33rd 66th nodes .

### My XSLT code :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

<xsl:key name="routes-by-origin" match="/schedules/Routes/org" use="./text()"/>
<xsl:template match="schedules" name="Main">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr> <td> Heading </td> </tr>
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="Routes/org[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('routes-by-origin',.)[1])]">
   <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Routes[org/text() = current()/text()]"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
   </xsl:template>
```

Template design called from above template

```
   <xsl:template match="Routes">
  <xsl:value-of select="des/text()"/>
<xsl:variable name="via" select="Via/text()"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="Flgno/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Input Document

```
<schedules>
    <Routes>
        <org>Agartala</org>
        <des>Bangalore</des>
        <Flgno>SG 872</Flgno>
        <Via>CCU, HYD</Via>
    </Routes>
    <Routes>
        <org>Agartala</org>
        <des>Guwahati</des>
        <Flgno>SG 873</Flgno>
        <Via> BOM </Via>
    </Routes>
    <Routes>
        <org>Agartala</org>
        <des>Hyderabad</des>
        <Flgno>SG 872</Flgno>
        <Via>CCU</Via>
    </Routes>
    <Routes>
        <org>Agartala</org>
        <des>Kolkata</des>
        <Flgno>SG 872</Flgno>
        <Via> - </Via>
    </Routes>
    <Routes>
        <org>Agartala</org>
        <des>Kolkata</des>
        <Flgno>SG 874</Flgno>
        <Via> - </Via>
    </Routes>
    <Routes>
        <org>Agartala</org>
        <des>Mumbai</des>
        <Flgno>SG 874</Flgno>
        <Via>CCU</Via>
    </Routes>
    <Routes>
        <org>Ahmedabad</org>
        <des>Bangalore</des>
        <Flgno>SG 528</Flgno>
        <Symbols> - </Symbols>
        <Via>BOM</Via>
    </Routes>
</schedules>
```

## Expected Result

My output should be in three tables in one page:
in first table 
first 2 records 
second table - next 2 records
third table last 3 records

2 records


2 records


3 records

```
<table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Agartala</td>
            <td>Bangalore</td>
            <td>SG 872</td>
            <td>CCU</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Agartala</td>
            <td>Guwahati</td>
            <td>SG 87</td>
            <td>BOM</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Agartala</td>
            <td>Hyderabad</td>
            <td>SG 872 </td>
            <td>CCU</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Agartala</td>
            <td>Kolkatta</td>
            <td>SG 872</td>
            <td> - </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Agartala</td>
            <td>Kolkatta</td>
            <td>SG 874</td>
            <td> - </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Agartala</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
            <td>SG 874 </td>
            <td>CCU</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Agartala</td>
            <td>Bangalore</td>
            <td>SG 528</td>
            <td>BOM</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</table>
```

Note : My input data is dynamic

Comment: Please supply sample input document, expected output from that input and your XSLT version.

Comment: supplied input and expected output and version of xslt is 1.0

Comment: Please supply the expected result for the given input, as a listing, not just a narrative. It's unclear if you want 3 separate output documents (one per table), or one output document with the 3 tables listed in sequence?

Comment: i have given the expected output which should be in three tables in one page only

Comment: Something is a bit odd here. Are you sure you don't want <tr> and <td> elements?

Comment: In any case, I believe your question is already asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739105 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938438 . Any difference in your question is only a minor variation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split large table into several smaller tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739105/split-large-table-into-several-smaller-tables)

Comment: yes i need it i updated with <tr> <td>

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet is a copy of Dimitre's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739105), slightly tweaked for the OP's particular data and having the 3rd table have ceil( row-count / 3) rows.

## XSLT 1.0 Solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="prowLimit" select="floor(count(/*/Routes) div 3)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <table>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Routes" />
 </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Routes">
 <xsl:if test="(position() mod $prowLimit = 1) and 
               (position() &lt; (3 * $prowLimit + 1))"> 
  <xsl:variable name="is-last-table" select="position() - (2*$prowLimit)" />               
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::Routes[
      not(position() > $prowLimit - 1) or ($is-last-table > 0)]" >
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="org" /></td> 
       <td><xsl:value-of select="des" /></td> 
       <td><xsl:value-of select="Flgno" /></td> 
       <td><xsl:value-of select="Via" /></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>  
  </table>
 </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

## XSLT 2.0 Solution

It gets easier in XSLT 2.0 ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl fn">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="prowLimit" select="floor(count(/*/Routes) div 3)" /> 
 <table>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="*/Routes"
       group-adjacent="fn:min((floor((position() - 1) div $prowLimit),2))" >
     <table>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
     </table>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Routes">
      <tr>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="org" /></td> 
       <td><xsl:value-of select="des" /></td> 
       <td><xsl:value-of select="Flgno" /></td> 
       <td><xsl:value-of select="Via" /></td>
      </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```